# Repeating Sampling with Replacement and storing Correlation Coefficients

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation, bootstrapping

I am very new to coding and I am attempting to preform sampling with replacement. So far I have been able to generate several randomised datasets and their correlation coefficients, however I cannot seem to get the correlations to store within a variable, it keeps showing up with only one correlation and not x amount as the loop output gives. I need to be able to use the array for correlation coefficients to produce a histogram and report the confidence interval (essentially bootstrapping).

Here is what I’ve gotten so far:

```
correlation = np.array([])
for i in range (num_datasets):
    sample_datasets = dataset[np.random.choice(dataset.shape[0],size[0],size=dataset,shape[0],replace=True)]
  for i in sample_dataset:
    corr = np.corrcoef(sample_dataset[:,0], sample_dataset[:,1])[0,1]
  correlation = np.append(corr)
  print (correlation)
```

I have tried several variations of this code but it usually keeps only storing just one element to the correlation so I cannot reorder it or do anything.

Comment: Your code is accessing some values that are not defined in your code (`shape` and `sample_dataset`) - are these typos in your code, or could you share more relevant code?  You've described roughly what you need and what you're getting, but it's generally a good idea to share (some) actual output and give an example of what you'd expected instead.

Comment: Some other things to note. (1) your indentation is off, so it's unclear how your code runs. (2) numpy `append` is not the same as the python list append, so your code will not work. Please read the documentation on that function.

Comment: @Grismar I said it was off because the second line is 4 spaces while the third is 2 spaces. That is not consistent with any proper indentation.

Comment: @jared, you're right - I missed that somehow. Removed my comment to avoid confusion.